# Buy now button and thankyou page for my website?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, paypal

I want to activate Paypal 'Buy Now' button for my products. After purchasing product it needs redirection to thank you page. How to do this via a plugin?

Is there any plugin available for this task? Please recommend a plugin or an easy way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wordpress plugins you can see the below links

1. http://wpmu.org/8-wordpress-paypal-plugins-for-receiving-payments-and-donations/
2. http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart-plugin-768
3. http://www.bestwpplugins.net/wordpress-plugins-for-paypal-integration.html

---

**Check this plugin link it might work in your case and its tested in wordpress 3.1 its working fine.**

url: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-easy-paypal-payment-or-donation-accept-plugin/

To customize the paypal payment and thankyou message you can code as per your requirement but u need to know the paypal api how it interact.

**To know about paypal html variable see the link:**

url: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

**To know more about paypal payment form see the good tutorial on net tuts+**

url: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-paypal-payment-form/